# Why my custom ApplicationListener listening on DataSourceInitializedEvent hasn't been called during the application start up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wrote an application using spring boot. I added an ApplicationListener listening on the DataSourceInitializedEvent, but my listener hasn't been called during the application start up. Following is my DataSourceInitializedEvent listenser:

```
package com.athena.edge;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Created by minggaoxi on 1/11/16.
 */
@Component
public class EdgeTestDatasourceListener implements ApplicationListener<DataSourceInitializedEvent> {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EdgeTestDatasourceListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializedEvent event) {
        logger.debug("EdgeTestDatasourceListener called");
    }
}
```

My main application looks like following:

```
package com.athena.edge;

import io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo;
import org.h2.tools.Server;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableZuulProxy
@RestController
public class EdgeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdgeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World from Edge-Server at " + new Date();
    }

    // Config H2 tcp server when we're in development stage, in order to
    // enable inspecting the in-memory database content from outside.
    @Bean(name = "org.h2.tools.Server", initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    @Profile("dev")
    public Server h2TcpServer() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9980");
    }

    // Configuration related to Zuul error handling in Undertow.
    // Refer to http://blog.jmnarloch.io/2015/09/16/spring-cloud-zuul-error-handling/
    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(new UndertowDeploymentInfoCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo) {
                deploymentInfo.setAllowNonStandardWrappers(true);
            }
        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I don't know why my listener wasn't called when the 'DataSourceInitializedEvent' was fired, however I noticed that the Spring internal 'DataSourceInitializer' was called.

Comment: I added a solution. Please, let me know if it helped. thx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that the  event is fired before your custom   listener is registered. This is due to  `DataSourceInitializer` being certainly initialized first.

The solution would be to implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and to make it dependent on `EdgeTestDatasourceListener`. This will garantee that the instance of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`  will be created after that of `EdgeTestDatasourceListener` and before all the other beans (especially `DataSourceInitializer`).

Otherwise, you don't need to write any code in `BeanFactoryPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory`. When Spring starts, it will detect this `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and invokes its `postProcessBeanFactory`, so you don't neither need to instantiate it.

To make `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` depend on `EdgeTestDatasourceListener`, you can use annotation `@DependsOn("classname")` over your implementaion of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`

```
 @Component
 @DependsOn("edgeTestDatasourceListener")
 public class DataSourceListenerRegistrarForcer  implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {  
 @Override  
 public int getOrder() {  
    return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;  
 }  
 @Override  
 public void postProcessBeanFactory(  
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {  
 }  
}
```

Comment: I followed your approach, and wrote a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as follows: `@DependsOn("edgeTestDatasourceListener")
@Component
public class DataSourceListenerRegistrarForcer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    }
}`, but seems it still doesn't work. My `EdgeTestDatasourceListener` still was not called when the `DataSourceInitializedEvent` was fired.

Comment: I updated my post to force the order of BFPP if there is more than one. In the other hand,

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my code as yours, but it seems still don't work. I don't know where I made mistakes. Are there other possible reasons lead to this failure?